# Is the rotor described in this Kickstarter new?

Tags: blade, quadcopter

[A NewAtlas story](https://newatlas.com/whisper-drone/55461/) linked to a [Kickstarter for a the "Whisper Drone"](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1494649332/whisper-drone-a-new-kind-of-flying-machine/description) that shows a CAD model of a rotor that the Kickstartee-aspirant has apparently 3D-printed and flown (four of) on a quadcopter.  I find the rotor strongly reminiscent of something I can't place.

Is the rotor design new?  If not, what is it (presumably a variant of)?

Comment: It looks a lot like the impeller from an old Morphy Richards hair dryer I owned years ago.

Comment: I believe this is essentially a centrifugal duct fan that you'll find in some vacuum cleaners -   http://www.heko-electronic.com/home-ventilation/vacuum-cleaner/ec-centrifugal-duct-fan-for-vacuum-cleaner.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotors on that drone are of the [centrifugal fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_fan) type. They are not new in design (don't know about aircraft use though) and can be found in all kinds of everyday appliances: hairdryers, vacuum cleaners, car A/C blowers, etc. They move air at a 90° angle, sucking it in from the top and expelling it from the side.

Apparently they are more silent in this application than a normal propeller (or so the kickstarter claims) but it is easy to spot some downsides. Weight for one thing, as it seems they need a lot more material for construction than a normal prop.

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like the ramp that drops out toward the edge also provides an axial thrust component.  I agree it seems like a variant of a centrifugal fan though.